# How do I use netplan to configure PPPoE?

Tags: 17.10, pppoe, netplan

I want to add lines to a working `01-netcfg-yaml` file to automatically connect an interface to `ppp` using a script created by `pppoeconf`.

But I can't find any guides or examples.

I would much appreciate a "howto" help to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This was originally a question about getting PPPoE to work in conjunction with netplan, which I've answered below. To "run custom scripts once an interface comes up" is really a different (but very valid) more general question, so I'm not sure it made sense to have edited the original question to this, especially as the answer to the original question isn't necessarily implemented by running a custom script when an interface is brought up.

Answer (score 5):

I've configured my PPPoE router running Ubuntu using netplan for the regular Ethernet interface and directly using systemd for the PPPoE interface.

For the PPP part, I left the PPPoE interface out of netplan entirely and created a `/etc/systemd/system/ppp.service` file as follows. `ens7` is my interface that is connected to my PPPoE modem, which you'll need to change (every occurence) to your case. I'm also using baby jumbo frames by setting my MTU to 1508. If your NIC or ISP can't handle this, then you should remove that line:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens7.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens7.device

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set mtu 1508 dev ens7
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set up dev ens7
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/pppd call provider
Type=forking
SuccessExitStatus=5
PIDFile=/run/ppp-pppoe.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=sys-subsystem-net-devices-ens7.device
```

My `/etc/ppp/peers/provider` looks like this. Again, `ens7` is my PPPoE interface; you'll need to change it to your own one below, along with `my_username_with_my_isp`. If your hardware (or ISP) can't handle baby jumbo frames and you deleted the mtu line above, then also change `mtu` and `mru` below to 1492. I'm also enabling ipv6 here. Add `usepeerdns` if you want your ISP's provided DNS servers to be used (instead of having them statically configured).

```
user my_username_with_my_isp
plugin rp-pppoe.so
ens7
noipdefault
defaultroute
hide-password
lcp-echo-interval 20
lcp-echo-failure 3
noauth
persist
maxfail 0
mtu 1500
mru 1500
noaccomp
default-asyncmap
+ipv6
linkname pppoe
```

My `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` looks like this. You may need to use `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets` instead if your ISP doesn't support CHAP.

```
* * my_password_with_my_isp
```

To put it all together on 18.04:

1. Install the `ppp` package.
2. Create/edit `/etc/systemd/system/ppp.service`, `/etc/ppp/peers/provider` and `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` as above.
3. Run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`, `sudo systemctl enable ppp` and then `sudo systemctl start ppp`.
4. Use `systemctl status ppp` and view `/var/log/syslog` for PPP status.

Comment: Probably a stupid question but how did you configure `ens7` in netplan config yaml?

Comment: I didn't. `ens7` is deliberately left out of the netplan config yaml. It is configured in `ppp.service` and within pppd (via its PPPoE plugin) only. netplan isn't told about `ens7` so it doesn't do anything to it.

Comment: Although you say it, it would be good to say "pppoe" configuration is not supported by netplan. You answer helped me but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: I had to set pid to `PIDFile=/run/ppp0.pid` to make it work.

Comment: This is working but how can we achieve same for multiple pppoe interfaces

Answer (score 2):

There is an option if you're happy to do some tinkering.  `networkd-dispatcher` can help you run your own scripts to do what you need, and roughly follows the syntax for scripts in /etc/network/.

https://github.com/craftyguy/networkd-dispatcher

Also, this is now accepted into Bionic (18.04) in the  "universe" repository:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/networkd-dispatcher/1.7-0ubuntu1

```
# Install
sudo apt install networkd-dispatcher

# Documentation
man networkd-dispatcher
```