# ubuntu 18.04 netplan support ppp interface with specific ISP provider

Tags: 18.04, usb-modem, netplan, ppp

Sorry about this could be FAQ but I did not find any useful information on Internet/Google. I setup a 4G/LTE modem on a Ubuntu 18.04 and it is verified by "sudo pon/poff provider".

The next step could be similar to:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
   allow-hotplug ppplte0
   iface ppplte0 inet ppp
   provider isp

sudo ifup --allow=hotplug ppplte0
sudo ifquery --state ppplte0
sudo ifdown ppplte0
```

Any equivalent set-up by netplan? For if{up/query/down} commands, I would like to put it into systemd to start/stop when system is boot-up or shutdown.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/987982/how-do-i-use-netplan-to-configure-pppoe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netplan does not support integration with ppp.  Ifupdown continues to be supported in Ubuntu 18.04 for such use cases.